# Seeing numbers in Ruby with r attached to the number

Tags: ruby

When you come across numbers that look like this in Ruby code, what does it mean?

```
1r
```

Or

```
1.0r
```

Tested in Ruby 1.8.6 up to 2.0.0 and it fails. with something like this:

```
>> 1r
SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
```

and

```
>> 1.0r
SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
```

Probably downvoted for not searching, or something, or not enough examples.  Hopefully this clarifies.  It is just Ruby Code, it doesn't have to be specifically anywhere, just has to be there.

Comment: Where are you seeing those numbers with an appended 'r'?

Comment: That still doesn't really make it clear. **Where** are you seeing numbers that look like this in Ruby code?

Comment: In an e-mail question.  They obviously saw it somewhere as well.

Comment: @Chuck Apparently in Ruby 2.1.0-preview Code.  If I had known that, I could have answered your question better, but then I would not have posted this question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a new feature for Decimal/Rational Literals in Ruby 2.1. See here: http://rkh.im/ruby-2.1 (search for "Decimal Literals")

```
0.1r      #=> (1/10)
0.1r * 3  #=> (3/10)
```

Comment: God answer. I guess the question was bad.  Sorry for that.

Comment: The preview of Ruby 2.1 was announced yesterday. Therefore: No, was not a bad question... ;-)